# change the Listview dimensions dynamically with respect to the phone screen

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

How can change the position of the list view dynamically.For example my list view initially covers 2/4 of the screen and on scroll down ,I want the list will size to expand and cove 3/4 of the screen.

below code is giving me whether user is scrolling up or down in the list view

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    final ListView lw = lv;
    if (view.getId() == lw.getId()) {
        final int currentFirstVisibleItem = lw.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
            mIsScrollingUp = false;
        }
        else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
            mIsScrollingUp = true;
        }

        mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What does your layout contains and what will be removed in order to make the list bigger?(could you provide the layout?)

Comment: @Laviniux --except list view my layout has 2 relative layout which contain 3 and 4 text views respectively.

Comment: I think this is more a problem of design, because having the list change its size dynamically is something the users don't expect and it could lead to strange behavior. My suggestion would be to think how you could change the layout: add the texts that you always want to see on the screen as headers/footers to the list and the others as part of the list (you can have more types of list items) so when the list is scrolled the other elements will fill more of the screen space

Comment: @Laviniux ya u may be right on that but any how i have partially achieved the required thing. by using only the View.Gone for other view except list view and the list view is conversing the gone view space. How ever the reson i am telling partially becoz the view are going in flash i need make these view.gone action more smoth.thank for your time and suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a layout (a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) and a transparent view whose visibility may change to GONE.
Something like:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <ListView android:layout_height="0px"  android:layout_weight="1" .../>
    <View android:background="@null" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:visibility="gone" ...>
    <View android:background="@null" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:visibility="visible" ...>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you change the visibility of the 2nd layout item from gone to visible, the ListView will change its height from 2/3 to 1/2 of the LinearLayout height.

Disclaimer: I myself find the idea of changing the ListView height very counter-intuitive.

Just in case: View.[getMeasuredHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight%28%29) gives the real height but you may have to define a [ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) to get notified when it becomes calculated. When you react on input events, the measured height is already calculated.

Comment: Hi, I have mentioned that i need change the view dynamically

Comment: I mean that dynamically you will do _view.setVisibility(View.GONE)_ or _view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)_

Answer (score 0):

That is achieved by using [DisplayManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html) class. Sorry I haven't tested the following code, but it should work, although you might need to fix some errors and constraints, the logic is fine:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    Display mainDisplay = ((DisplayManager)Context.getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE)).getDisplay(0);
    Point screenSize = new Point();
    mainDisplay.getSize(screenSize);
    view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(screenSize.x * 3 / 4, screenSize.y * 3 / 4));
    //rest of your code
}
```

However, the problem you'll be facing afterwards is that your ListView won't revert back once you stop scrolling, you need to create an additional method (and Event handler) that would accomplish that.

Comment: I tried buts its not working.actually i solved the issue and will post the answer by tomorrow